# Upgrading from impish to jammy : self-perpetuating "404 Not Found" loop

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I run Ubuntu 21.10 (impish) and didn't pay attention to the fact that it was going EOL. Now I'm stuck in this loop:

- To release-upgrade, I first have to upgrade current packages.
- To upgrade current packages (`update && upgrade`), I have to release-upgrade because impish repos no longer exist.

The outputs of `do-release-upgrade`, `apt update`, and `apt upgrade` can be found at the end of this post.

I've been searching online for a while and also tried `dist-upgrade` and variations of apt commands with `--fix-missing`, but nothing works. No clean way of getting out of this conundrum.

There are accounts of people manually swapping all `impish` to `jammy` in their `/etc/apt/sources.list` and claiming that "it works", but I'm not sure about how much of a mess that would cause since apt is clearly not meant to be used that way when dist-upgrading.

Does anyone know of a safer method?

**Outputs:**

Output of `$ sudo do-release-upgrade` :

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Output of `$ sudo apt update` :

```
Ign:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                                   
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                                                                            
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cartes/drawing/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:5 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:6 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease                                                                                                   
Get:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish InRelease [48.9 kB]                                                                                                    
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                                                                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:10 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                                       
Ign:11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:14 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                     
Ign:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease                                                           
Err:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease
Err:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Hit:19 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release              
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Output of `$ sudo apt upgrade` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
  virtualbox-qt
9 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 92.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 810 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 isc-dhcp-client amd64 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 isc-dhcp-common amd64 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Ign:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt all 1:21.10.10
Ign:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:21.10.10
Ign:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:21.10.10
Err:6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-qt amd64 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-dkms amd64 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox amd64 6.1.34-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Ign:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso all 6.1.34-1~ubuntu1.21.10.1
Err:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt all 1:21.10.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:21.10.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:21.10.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
Err:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso all 6.1.34-1~ubuntu1.21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/isc-dhcp-client_4.4.1-2.3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/isc-dhcp-common_4.4.1-2.3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt_21.10.10_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_21.10.10_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/python3-distupgrade_21.10.10_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox/virtualbox-qt_6.1.34-dfsg-3%7eubuntu1.21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox/virtualbox-dkms_6.1.34-dfsg-3%7eubuntu1.21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox/virtualbox_6.1.34-dfsg-3%7eubuntu1.21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso_6.1.34-1%7eubuntu1.21.10.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 51.158.154.169 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Because you are trying to *release-upgrade* too late (ie. after EOL) there is an extra step required as documented here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: ie.  you need to make that change so you can then *apply all the upgrades you were missing*, then *release-upgrade* can be executed.